# difference about authorities between userdetails and clientdetails

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm learning spring oauth2 framework, and want to custom users and clients by using database storage, but I'm very confuse about one thing, the interface of both userdetails and clientdetails have a field "authorities", are they the same things? if not how can I specify the authorities about my protected resource separately with user and client? if they point to the same thing, which one is useless? By the way I use annotation to configure the application.